# How to install the latest version of GraphicsMagick on windows

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

GraphicsMagick released a new version in 2022 which does not have an associated .exe installer file , I downloaded the latest version .7z file but it does not have an installer. On the other hand the older version does not work on my system the "gm" cmd commands return blank .  Any help would be appreciated .
I have already installed ghostscript and imageMagick

Comment: I don't understand. What was the purpose of installing **ImageMagick** if you want **GraphicsMagick**? As you have **ImageMagick** installed why not use that?

Comment: The npm module "compare-pdf" I am using for some reason requires both.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I downloaded it but it doesn't have an installer"*? Did you install it or not? If the `.7z` extension is confusing you, you can install https://www.7-zip.org to unpack it.